# User keeps getting logged out switching pages

Tags: php, session

For a project I am doing, I am using PHP to which I am still very new to. When a user signs in, or logs in, they are directed to the home page, where I am using `$_SESSION` to log them in. `$_SESSION['user']` is used by having the session store their username. But, when I try to switch from the home page to the profile page (to which they do by clicking on their name), it sends me back to the login screen, effectively logging them out, as if they don't have a session anymore. I looked at my code, and I don't know what I am doing wrong, or not doing. Could someone tell me what is wrong, and how to keep my users logged in when navigating other pages?

Here is my signup.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

/**
 * Include ircmaxell's password_compat library.
 */
require 'lib/password.php';

/**
 * Include our MySQL connection.
 */
require 'connect.php';


//If the POST var "register" exists (our submit button), then we can
//assume that the user has submitted the registration form.
if(isset($_POST['signUp'])){

    //Retrieve the field values from our registration form.
    $firstName = !empty($_POST['firstName']) ? trim($_POST['firstName']) : null;
    $lastName = !empty($_POST['lastName']) ? trim($_POST['lastName']) : null;
    $userName = !empty($_POST['userName']) ? trim($_POST['userName']) : null;
    $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;
    $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

    //TO ADD: Error checking (username characters, password length, etc).
    //Basically, you will need to add your own error checking BEFORE
    //the prepared statement is built and executed.

    //Now, we need to check if the supplied username already exists.

    //Construct the SQL statement and prepare it.
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(Username) AS num FROM users WHERE Username = :username";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    //Bind the provided username to our prepared statement.
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $userName);

    //Execute.
    $stmt->execute();

    //Fetch the row.
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //If the provided username already exists - display error.
    //TO ADD - Your own method of handling this error. For example purposes,
    //I'm just going to kill the script completely, as error handling is outside
    //the scope of this tutorial.
    if($row['num'] > 0){
        die('That username is already in use.');
    }

    //Hash the password as we do NOT want to store our passwords in plain text.
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));

    //Prepare our INSERT statement.
    //Remember: We are inserting a new row into our users table.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, Username, email, Password) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :username, :email, :password)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    //Bind our variables.
    $stmt->bindValue(':firstName', $firstName);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lastName', $lastName);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $userName);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $hash);

    //Execute the statement and insert the new account.
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    //If the signup process is successful.
    if($result){
        //What you do here is up to you!
        echo 'You are registered.';
        $_SESSION['user'] = $userName;
//             return $userName;
//      //die('debug');
        header('Location: home.php');
    }

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sign Up</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Index Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/signup.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Animate.css -->
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this website -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fugaz+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h1 id="loginPrompt">Sign Up</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post"
        action="signup.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">First
                Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName2"
                    name="firstName" placeholder="John">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName2"
                class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName2"
                    name="lastName" placeholder="Doe">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUserName"
                class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUserName"
                    name="userName" placeholder="JDoe">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3"
                class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"
                    name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3"
                class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3"
                    name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-2">
                <button type="submit" name="signUp" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class = "col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h3 id="signUpMessage"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Login.php:

```
<?php


// if(isset($_POST['submit']))
// {
//  $Username = $_POST['email'];
//  $email= $_POST['email'];
//  $Password = $_POST['password'];

//  if($user->login($Username,$email,$Password))
//  {
//      $user->redirect('home.php');
//  }
//  else
//  {
//      $error = "Your Credentials Are Incorrect.";
//  }
// }

//login.php

/**
 * Start the session.
 */
session_start();

/**
 * Include ircmaxell's password_compat library.
 */
require 'lib/password.php';

/**
 * Include our MySQL connection.
 */
require 'connect.php';




//If the POST var "login" exists (our submit button), then we can
//assume that the user has submitted the login form.
if($_POST){

    //Retrieve the field values from our login form.
    $userName = !empty($_POST['userName']) ? trim($_POST['userName']) : null;
    $passwordAttempt = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

    //Retrieve the user account information for the given username.
    $sql = "SELECT UserID, Username, Password FROM users WHERE Username = :username";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    //Bind value.
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $userName);

    //Execute.
    $stmt->execute();

    //Fetch row.
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //If $row is FALSE.
    if($user === false){
        //Could not find a user with that username!
        //PS: You might want to handle this error in a more user-friendly manner!
        echo 'The username does not exist.';
    } else{
        //User account found. Check to see if the given password matches the
        //password hash that we stored in our users table.

        //Compare the passwords.
        $validPassword = password_verify($passwordAttempt,  $user['Password']);

        //If $validPassword is TRUE, the login has been successful.
        if($validPassword){
            //Provide the user with a login session.
            $_SESSION['user'] = $userName;
            //             return $user['Username'];
            //          return true;

            //die('debug');
            //Redirect to our protected page, which we called home.php
            header('Location: home.php');

        } else{
            echo 'The user credentials do not match.';
        }
    }

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="Landing Page">
    <meta name="author" content="Jordan C. McRae">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Login Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this website -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fugaz+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h1 id="loginPrompt">Log In</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post"
        action="login.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputUserName" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUserName" name="userName" placeholder="JDoe">
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-2">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-2">
      <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

home.php:

```
<?php


session_start();

require 'connect.php';
/**
 * Check if the user is logged in.
 */
// if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
//  //User not logged in. Redirect them back to the login.php page.
//  header('Location: login.php');
//  exit;
// }

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location: login.php");  }

    $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE Username = :username";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    //Bind value.
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['user']);

    //Execute.
    $stmt->execute();

    //Fetch row.
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/**
 * Print out something that only logged in users can see.
 */

echo 'Congratulations! You are logged in!';

?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>My Closet</title>

   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Login Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this website -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fugaz+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="profile.php" class="navbar-brand animated fadeInLeft"><?php echo $user['firstName'], " ", $user['lastName'];?></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right animated fadeInRight">
            <li><a href="home.php">My Closet</a></li>
            <li><a href="shoe.php">Post Shoes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li><a class="logout" href="index.html">Logout</a><?php session_destroy();?></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Find Shoes">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 home">
          <h1 class="home-header">My Closet</h1>
        <?php 

        ?>
          <div class="row placeholders">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Shoe</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Size</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Shoe</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Size</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Shoe</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Size</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Shoe</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Size</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Shoe</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Size</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And profile.php:

```
<?php


session_start();

require 'connect.php';
/**
 * Check if the user is logged in.
 */
// if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
// //User not logged in. Redirect them back to the login.php page.
// header('Location: login.php');
// exit;
// }

if (! isset ( $_SESSION ['user'] )) {
    header ( "Location: login.php" );
}

$sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE Username = :username";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare ( $sql );

// Bind value.
$stmt->bindValue ( ':username', $_SESSION ['user'] );

// Execute.
$stmt->execute ();

// Fetch row.
$user = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

/**
 * Print out something that only logged in users can see.
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>Profile</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Login Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this website -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fugaz+One'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="profile.php" class="navbar-brand animated fadeInLeft">
                    <?php echo $user['firstName'], " ", $user['lastName'];?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right animated fadeInRight">
                    <li><a href="home.php">My Closet</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shoe.php">Post Shoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a class="logout" href="index.html">Logout</a> <?php session_destroy();?></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Find Shoes">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 profile">
        <h1 class="profile-header"><?php echo $user['firstName'], " ", $user['lastName'];?></h1>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h3><?php echo $user['address']?></h3>
            <h3><?php echo $user['city'], ", ", $user['state'], "", $user['zip']?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>





    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.jQuery
                || document
                        .write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As I said, I am still new to PHP, and I have looked at similar questions before posting mine, but I'm still stuck and confused. Anything and everything will help. Thank you kindly.

UPDATE:

I looked at another post here on Stack Overflow about how someone has a 12-hour session for users, and I tried to implement something similar to my code, but PHP kept telling me a session was already started, and it still logged me out when I tried other pages, so I'm still trying to figure it out, but I'm still not making any success.

Comment: start by checking for errors and do a bit of `var_dump()`'ing. You should also add `exit;` after each header. Otherwise, your code may want to continue to execute.

Comment: So, I'd want to do `var_dump($_SESSION['user'])`, then?

Comment: What happens when you are on the Home.php and press F5 in the browser?

Comment: @NineBerry it still takes me to login.php.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Is register_globals on on your server? Do you have cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: @NineBerry I have cookies enabled on my browser, but I'm not sure about register_globals. I have PHP version 7.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `home.php` and `profile.php` here:

```
<li><a class="logout" href="index.html">Logout</a><?php session_destroy();?></li>
```

The call to `session_destroy()` is executed while the page is being rendered, so every time, not when the user clicks on the link as you expect. You need to remove the call to `session_destroy()` there. Instead link to a different specific page for logout.

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you for all your help, @NineBerry!